# mysql : how to ignore ‘on update’ when update some records?

Tags: mysql

when define the table, the field has `update_at timestamp ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`  attr. but now I want to update some columns and not to modify  the update_at. how to ignore the effect of `on update`?

Comment: I think you would have to alter the column, make your changes, and if you want, alter back. Test it first.

Comment: You got a couple good answers. I'd recommend that you put closure to your question by marking one of them as accepted. You can do so by clicking on a tick mark beside the answer of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to do test this correctly for your specific use case, but I just tested around a bit with my own and the following worked well for what you describe.

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
    ALTER `timestamp` DROP DEFAULT;
ALTER TABLE `test`
    CHANGE COLUMN `timestamp` `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL AFTER `value`;
```

Then make the updates...

To change back use:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`
    CHANGE COLUMN `timestamp` `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER `value`;
```

This kept the earlier timestamps without changing or losing any of them.

Answer (score 0):

There's another option - well, two options. Let's say this was your table.

```
create table test (id int, update_at timestamp on update current_timestamp);
insert into test values (1, current_timestamp), (2, current_timestamp);
select * from test;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | update_at           |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2020-06-10 08:18:33 |
|    2 | 2020-06-10 08:18:33 |
+------+---------------------+
```

Let's say you want to update the ID 1 to ID 4.

1. You can update the update_at field with itself
2. You remember the update_at value for ID 1, update id 4 and replace update_at with remembered data

## Option 1

Normally, this would happen. DB will auto-update update_at because you didn't provide any data for that field.

```
update test set id = 4 where id = 1;
mysql> select * from test;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | update_at           |
+------+---------------------+
|    4 | 2020-06-10 08:21:11 |
|    2 | 2020-06-10 08:18:33 |
+------+---------------------+
```

So, why don't we just tell DB to use the same timestamp it had? Let's do that and ensure that your timestamp remains unchanged.

```
update test set id = 6, update_at = update_at where id = 2;
mysql> select * from test
    -> ;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | update_at           |
+------+---------------------+
|    4 | 2020-06-10 08:21:11 |
|    6 | 2020-06-10 08:18:33 |
+------+---------------------+
```

Notice that ID 6 (which was ID 2) has the same timestamp as before.

## Option 2

You would remember update_at in a temporary variable and then apply that temporary variable when you do the update.

```
select update_at into @temp_update_at from test where id = 6;
mysql> select @temp_update_at;
+---------------------+
| @temp_update_at     |
+---------------------+
| 2020-06-10 08:18:33 |
+---------------------+

mysql> update test set id = 12, update_at = @temp_update_at where id = 6;    
mysql> select * from test;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | update_at           |
+------+---------------------+
|    4 | 2020-06-10 08:21:11 |
|   12 | 2020-06-10 08:18:33 |
+------+---------------------+
```

You have now retained your timestamp.